# Optimized way of generating large number of hashes

Tags: java

Currently, the way I am implementing the generation of hashes is not scalable. I monitored the running in visualVM and saw too much of CPU time is being spent in `MessageDigest`. Here is the code:

```
public static byte[] getHash(byte[] value) {
        HashCode hashCode = hashFunction.newHasher().putBytes(value).hash();
        return hashCode.asBytes();
    }
```

The method above is called in a loop:

```
List<byte[]> someList; 
for(byte[] payload : someMap.values()) {
            someList.add(getHash(payload));
        }
```

Basically, I have a `map<SomeObject, byte[] payload)` and I need to hash individual values and put them in a `List<byte[]>`. Am using guava's hasher and the input map will be huge. Is there anything I can do better here?
The reason I need to hash all these values is because I need to store them in HBase.

**EDIT** The hashing algorithm I use here is `MD5`

Comment: I would look for a simpler hash, one that operates directly on the byte array.  The hash algorithm used in String is probably fairly decent: `s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]`.  If you look at the source the algorithm is a simple for loop with `h = 31*h + val[off++];` inside,.

Comment: Some hash functions will operate faster -- and none will operate slower -- if you use `hashFunction.hashBytes(value)` instead of `hashFunction.newHasher().putBytes(value).hash()`.

Answer (score 1):

Cryptographically secure hashing process is very CPU-intensive, so there's very little you could do to optimize your code further. I assume that is is not possible to make your `value` arrays significantly shorter.

One thing you could do to have your loop finish faster is parallelizing the process: if your processor has multiple cores, you could distribute the computation among these cores by feeding the data into several worker threads that compute the MD5 hashes and give you back the results.

> I need the output to be ordered

One way to achieve this would making a queue of pairs of `{Integer, byte[]}` that pair up the bytes to be hashed with their respective index in the output list. Resizing the list `someList` upfront should let you avoid having to synchronize writing the results back into the list.

Comment: I did think of that but here is the catch (or maybe its not). I need the output to be ordered (its an ordered map), so the threads need to be somehow be in sync and I cannot use joins as it would make no difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you use these hash codes as validators, you might want to stick with MD5 or SHA1. But if you use these hash codes as identifiers for which collisions, although not preferred, are no game breaker, than there are many fast alternatives you can consider. Bob Jenkin's One-at-a-time hash is very fast and very good. You can easily convert that algorithm to generate more sizable hash codes very fast.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your application, it looks like you do not need a cryptographically secure one-way hash, since you're using the hash value only as a unique database index, and not for tamper detection. So there's no point in using so much CPU to derive a pseudo-unique value for an object when you could use a simple but faster arithmetic mashing algorithm instead, which computes a value by combining some of the bytes of the object you're hashing.

A simple string-base hashing algorithm I uses years ago, derived from an older algorithm originally from Bell Labs, was something like this:

```
int hash1(byte[] key)
{
    int     h = 0;
    for (int i = 0;  i < key.length;  i++)
        h = ((h << 3) | (h >>> 32-3)) ^ key[i];
    return h;
}
```

You can adapt this to use whatever portion of the object you want, or even the entire object.

**EDIT**

I replaced the `>>` operator with `>>>`, as per @Holger's suggestion below.

Comment: You should use `>>>` instead of `>>`; otherwise you risk your hash to be flooded by a `1` sign bit once it occurred. Or just use `Integer.rotateLeft` as it will not only do it correctly, it will likely be replaced by an appropriate CPU instruction if the native CPU supports it.

Answer (score 0):

on a multicore machine you could run multiple threads to compute those hashes in parallel, as there's no dependency between two input values.

on a dual core you would achieve a max speedup of 2